# Define personal autocomplete library

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I regularly have to program small applications for several very specific situations.
My mother language is Dutch so I define my variables in Dutch.
When I write this programs I try to use VIM.

In most of my programs I use the same syntax, so I wanted to make my own auto complete library. But because I have to switch regularly between language (from lisp to latex for example). Specifically I want to be able to load a library after I started vim.

I don't have a clue about how this library should look, but the easiest thing I could come up with is a word on every line.

Comment: At one point in time, someone, somewhere will hate very much you for not programming in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set complete+=k
set dict+=~/path/to/dict
```

Answer (score 2):

The cool thing about VIM is autocomplete happens from any open buffer.  In my opinion, you can load an "autocomplete file" in a buffer, then open your source file that you're going to work on, which will open in in another buffer, and you will get all your autocomplete goodness.  This will allow you to open and close whatever buffers you want autocomplete to recognize.  Effectively customizing your autocomplete for that particular session.